# Generar Excel con datos procedentes de mysql y php y librería PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

Tengo una aplicación en MVC y en el DAO correspondiente tengo una función que me devuelve CORRECTAMENTE los datos que necesito en un array para exportarlos a excel. En primer lugar, tengo un archivo llamado conexion.php:

```
    class Conectar{

    public static function conexion(){

        try{
            $db=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost:XXXX; dbname=xxx", "root", "root");
            $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $db->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
        }catch (Exception $e){
            die("Error".$e->getMessage());
            echo "Error en la línea: ".$e->getLine();
        }

        return $db;
    }

}
```

Después, el DAO. Aquí se puede ver el constructor y la función que me devuelve los datos que quiero sacar en excel:

```
class Empleado_reunion_DAO
{
    private $db;

    public function __construct()
    {
        require_once("conexion.php");
        $this->db=Conectar::conexion();
    }

    public function obtener_reunion_detallada_Excel($idReunion_fk)
{
    $consulta = $this->db->prepare("SELECT empleado_reunion.id, asunto, fecha, inicio, fin, costeEstimado, nombre, apellidos,
    departamento, costeHora FROM  empleado_reunion INNER JOIN empleado
    ON empleado_reunion.idEmpleado_fk = empleado.id INNER JOIN reunion ON empleado_reunion.idReunion_fk=reunion.id
    WHERE idReunion_fk= :idReunionfk");
    $mParams = array(':idReunionfk'=>$idReunion_fk);
    $consulta->execute($mParams);
    $arrayReuniones = array();
        while ($row=$consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
          $arrayReuniones[] = $row;
        }
        return $arrayReuniones;
    }
}
```

En mi archivo php que genera el excel tengo lo siguiente:

```
require_once "../vendor/autoload.php";
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;

$spread = new Spreadsheet();
$spread
    ->getProperties()
    ->setCreator("Meeting Manager")
    ->setLastModifiedBy('Meeting Manager')
    ->setTitle('Informe de reunión')
    ->setSubject('Excel de prueba')
    ->setDescription('Excel generado como prueba')
    ->setKeywords('PHPSpreadsheet')
    ->setCategory('Informes');

    require_once 'empleado_reunion_DAO.php';
    $dao = new Empleado_reunion_DAO(); //ESTA LÍNEA ME DA PROBLEMAS
    $listaReuniones = $dao->obtener_reunion_detallada_Excel(38);

    $spread->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
    ->setCellValue('A1', 'Asunto')
    ->setCellValue('B1', 'Fecha')
    ->setCellValue('C1', 'Comienzo')
    ->setCellValue('D1', 'Fin')
    ->setCellValue('E1', 'Coste')
    ->setCellValue('A2', $listaReuniones[0]['asunto'])
    ->setCellValue('B2', $listaReuniones[0]['fecha'])
    ->setCellValue('C2', $listaReuniones[0]['inicio'])
    ->setCellValue('D2', $listaReuniones[0]['fin'])
    ->setCellValue('E2', $listaReuniones[0]['costeEstimado']);

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="meeting_report.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spread, 'Xlsx');
$writer->save('php://output');

exit;
```

Todo funciona correctamente hasta que meto la línea:

```
$dao = new Empleado_reunion_DAO();
```

Si no meto esa línea ni nada que llame a la función que tengo en el DAO, me genera el excel correctamente, eso sí, no puedo meter los datos que me da el array y eso es justo lo que necesito.

Al llamar a esa función, lo que ocurre es que excel me dice que no puede abrir el archivo porque el formato no es compatible.

He mirado muchísima documentación y ejemplos y no encuentro el fallo.

¿Puede ser que no sea posible crear objetos que no sean compatibles con la librería?

He pensado en que quizá podrían traerse por $GET pero me parece muy poco estético...

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea? Gracias!

Comment: Muestra el constructor de tu clase `Empleado_reunion_DAO`. Si el código falla simplemente por poner esto: `new Empleado_reunion_DAO()` significa que en el constructor ocurre algo que daña el proceso de creación del archivo, eso puede ser un error que ocurre, algo que sacas por pantalla, etc.

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias! Al final lo saqué mandando los datos por GET: 
`$listaReunionesExcel = $dao->obtener_reunion_detallada_Excel($idReunion_fk);

        $data = serialize($listaReunionesExcel);
        $data = urlencode($data);
href='meetingReport.php?meeting_detail=".$data`

Comment: Y en el archivo que lo recibe:
`$miArray=unserialize($_GET["meeting_detail"]);`

Comment: Creo que así está bien. A mi parecer queda bastante limpio. En cualquier caso, he editado la pregunta para que puedas ver el constructor como me pediste. Por supuesto, tendré en cuenta tu opinión.

Comment: Pero... no entiendo mucho lo que me dices sobre `$_GET` ¿? En tu código no veo dónde recibes los datos con `$_GET` .Yo creo que estaba fallando porque en algún punto se levantaba un error o había alguna salida por pantalla que dañaba el proceso de creación del archivo. Todo lo que comentas de `unserialize` y demás me parece que estás complicando demasiado los procesos pero sin conocer el contexto no puede decirte nada en concreto.